# fadeIn() not working along with a delay()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a fadeIn() to work along with a delay, but for some reason the fadeIn() is not working. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
$('#text').delay(2000).show(0).fadeIn(4200);
```

```css
#text {color: blue;background-color: red;display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">
Text appear!
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `.show(0)`

```js
$("#text").delay(2000).fadeIn(4200);
```

```css
#text {color: blue;background-color: red;display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="text">
Text appear!
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is not say

```
.show()
```

How you setup the command is the same as saying

```
.css( "display", "block")
```

One thing you could do is

```
.show("slow");
```

instead of the FadeIn if you want a more jump in effect.

More information can be found at

http://api.jquery.com/show/